# How to draw a frame the same as a System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, frame, visual-styles

In WinForms how do I draw a frame the same as in a `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` control?

I tried to use `VisualStyleRenderer` with the `VisualStyleElement.TextBox.TextEdit.Normal` parameter but it draws a strange gray line.

`VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Normal` for a button works correctly.
It draws the face just as the button but for `TextBox` it draws a gray line border.

I used the following code:

```
private void panel1_Paint (object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStyleRenderer vsr = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.TextBox.TextEdit.Normal);
    vsr.DrawBackground (e.Graphics, new Rectangle (500, 12, 100, 20));

    vsr = new VisualStyleRenderer (VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Normal);
    vsr.DrawBackground (e.Graphics, new Rectangle (500, 47, 100, 23));
}
```

Look at the screenshot.

On the left are Edit and Button controls.

On the right is what gets drawn by `VisualStyleRenderer.DrawBackground`

[image]

Comment: Try `var renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer("Edit", 6, 1);` followed by `renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, rect);`  See [TextBoxRenderer is just drawing gray rectangles](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/46e66852-b52e-420d-8fe0-b717f86ecb18/textboxrenderer-is-just-drawing-gray-rectangles?forum=winforms)

Comment: Use 6, 3 to get the blue border.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh, wunderbar, or for you, would that be wonderlijk...

Comment: @Lars - Hehe, not quite, means "mystifying" in Dutch.  Well, could be what you meant, how they fumbled VSR is kinda mystifying :)

Comment: VisualStyleRenderer("Edit", 6, 1) works. Thank you Lars.